# Change the order of the objects in the array using a parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array of object like that:

```
const arr = [
  {number: 1, value: 50},
  {number: 2, value: 4},
  {number: 3, value: 33},
  {number: 4, value: 49},
  {number: 5, value: 92},
  {number: 6, value: 1},
  {number: 7, value: 49},
]
```

and:

```
const startBy = 3
```

then I want an other array like that:

```
const newArr = [
  {number: 3, value: 33},
  {number: 4, value: 49},
  {number: 5, value: 92},
  {number: 6, value: 1},
  {number: 7, value: 49},
  {number: 1, value: 50},
  {number: 2, value: 4},
]
```

that is, I want to “rearrange” the elements of the array such that the first element is the one with the field number equal to startBy and then the next in order.
The field number must always be in order, only that can vary from which item to start.

I don't know how I can do this thing..

Comment: can you share the final goal

Comment: @mehta-rohan The final goal is the main question

Comment: what do you want to achieve after you arrange the object?

Comment: how about this array `[{number:9},{number:3},{number:100}`, `startBy=3`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take the value as check for a delta if the value is smaller than the given value. Otherwise sort by delta.

```js
function sortBy(array, first) {
    array.sort(function (a, b) {
       return (a.number < first) - (b.number < first) || a.number - b.number;
    });
    return array;
}

const array = [{ number: 1, value: 50 }, { number: 2, value: 4 }, { number: 3, value: 33 }, { number: 4, value: 49 }, { number: 5, value: 92 }, { number: 6, value: 1 }, { number: 7, value: 49 }];
console.log(sortBy(array, 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Pretty easy:

1. Just sort the array,
2. then search where to split your array with a
   `findIndex`,
3. and finally `slice` the array in two part to create a
   new one ;)

```js
const arr = [
  {number: 1, value: 50},
  {number: 2, value: 4},
  {number: 3, value: 33},
  {number: 4, value: 49},
  {number: 5, value: 92},
  {number: 6, value: 1},
  {number: 7, value: 49},
];
const startBy = 3;

//Presorting the input array.
const sortedArray = arr.sort((a, b) => a.number-b.number);

//Finding the split index.
const splitIndex = sortedArray.findIndex(elt => elt.number === startBy);

//Slicing the array and creating a new one.
const result = [...sortedArray.slice(splitIndex), ...sortedArray.slice(0, splitIndex)];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: you assume a sorted array.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could just take out the first element of the sequence, and add it to the end until you've found the correct element.

example:

```
const arr = [
  {number: 1, value: 50},
  {number: 2, value: 4},
  {number: 3, value: 33},
  {number: 4, value: 49},
  {number: 5, value: 92},
  {number: 6, value: 1},
  {number: 7, value: 49},
]
undefined
function ReturnNewArray(array, value){
    while(array[0].number!=value){
        array.push(array.shift())
    }
    return array;
}
undefined
ReturnNewArray(arr,3);

0: {number: 3, value: 33}
1: {number: 4, value: 49}
2: {number: 5, value: 92}
3: {number: 6, value: 1}
4: {number: 7, value: 49}
5: {number: 1, value: 50}
6: {number: 2, value: 4}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand Carl. You remove the first array and put it at the end.
is the new first element the one you are looking for? no?
remove first element and add to the end. 
is the new first element the one you are looking for? yes!

Comment: This is basically enqueue and dequeue for Queues.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your initial array is sorted by the `number` property you could check if that property is less than your `startBy` and if the condition is true remove that element and push it

```
arr.map(o => {
  if (o.number < startBy) {
    arr.push(arr.shift());
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qQELxd?editors=0010)

Comment: why do you use `map` instead of `forEach`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to simply `sort` your `array` based on your `number` key . [More About sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
const arr = [
  {number: 1, value: 50},
  {number: 2, value: 4},
  {number: 3, value: 33},
  {number: 4, value: 49},
  {number: 5, value: 92},
  {number: 6, value: 1},
  {number: 7, value: 49},
]

arr.sort((a,b) => {
  return (a.number < 3) - (b.number < 3) || (a.number-b.number)
})
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also find where the element is in the array, and shift the original array that many positions:

```js
const arr = [{
    number: 1,
    value: 50
  },
  {
    number: 2,
    value: 4
  },
  {
    number: 3,
    value: 33
  },
  {
    number: 4,
    value: 49
  },
  {
    number: 5,
    value: 92
  },
  {
    number: 6,
    value: 1
  },
  {
    number: 7,
    value: 49
  },
]

const findPosition = (array, startBy) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].number == startBy) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}

const shiftArray = (array, positions) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < positions; i++) {
    const first = array.shift();
    array.push(first);
  }
  return array;
}

console.log(shiftArray(arr, findPosition(arr, 3)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Comments Inline with code

```js
let arr = [{number: 1, value: 50},{number: 2, value: 4},{number: 3, value: 33},{number: 4, value: 49},{number: 5, value: 92},{number: 6, value: 1},{number: 7, value: 49}]

// sort the array by number value

arr.sort((a,b) => a.number - b. number)

// push into new array via reduce every element until you find your starting number and then from there insert everything thereafter into new array at starting position by Array.unshift()

function startFromNumber(number) {
  return arr.slice(0).reduce((a, d, i, arrC) =>
    (d.number == number 
      ? (a.unshift(...arrC.slice(i)), arrC.length = 0) 
      : a.push(d)
    , a), [])
  
}

console.log(startFromNumber(3))
console.log(startFromNumber(5))
```